# Why does the text automatically highlight whenever I adding attributes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

One day the text inside an attribute I am currently typing just started highlighting and it's honestly really irritating. Sometimes it prevents shortcuts and it gets annoying when I'm typing a long piece of code. If I click anywhere within the word highlighted it does not go away, and I have to manually click outside of the word for the word to no longer be highlighted. I use VS code as a code editor, in case that's important. Included is a picture example of what I am talking about:[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the VS code feature that highlights symbolic occurrences. It can be turned off by searching for "Occurrences Highlight" in the settings. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I turned off the setting but nothing changed. Seems like that wasn't the setting doing this

Comment: Interesting, the described behavior goes away as soon as I uncheck that box. Maybe make sure that the workspace settings aren't conflicting with the user ones? Could try unchecking it in both configs just to be sure.

Comment: I tried that too and still nothing. Perhaps it's a different setting that was turned on by accident at some point?